# Is it more efficient to query on parent selectors or to append selectors to all children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 mirror sections on my DOM, one for `delivery` and one for `pickup`, where for each of the two, you have the same content, e.g.,:

```
<div class="main-section">
  <div class="description-content">
    <p><span class="to-emphasize"></span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="field-content">
    <input type="text" name="address"></input>
  </div>
  <div class="table-content">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

And so forth... basically really meaty chunks of elements. I'm wondering, as my jQuery requires quite a bit of targeting/ retargeting... what would be more efficient from the below options? Looking for any rules of thumb around this, rather than personal preferences for style. Thanks!

**Strategy A, add delivery/pickup selector to parent and query on parent**

```
<div class="main-section" data-type="delivery">
  <div class="description-content">
    <p><span class="to-emphasize"></span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="field-content">
    <input type="text" name="address"></input>
  </div>
  <div class="table-content">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

// example of jQuery code
$(".main-section[data-type='delivery'] input[name='address']").val("new value")
$(".main-section[data-type='delivery'] .to-emphasize").empty()
$(".main-section[data-type='delivery'] .to-emphasize").append("new value")
delivery_or_pickup = $(this).parents(".main-section").data("type")
$(".main-section[data-type='"+delivery_or_pickup+"']").hide()
```

**Strategy B, add delivery/pickup selector to all children that need querying**

```
<div class="main-section" data-type="delivery">
  <div class="description-content" data-type="delivery">
    <p><span class="to-emphasize" data-type="delivery"></span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="field-content" data-type="delivery">
    <input type="text" name="address" data-type="delivery"></input>
  </div>
  <div class="table-content" data-type="delivery">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

// example of jQuery code
$("input[name='address'][data-type='delivery']").val("new value")
$(".to-emphasize[data-type='delivery']").empty()
$(".to-emphasize[data-type='delivery']").append("new value")
delivery_or_pickup = $(this).data("type")
$(".main-section[data-type='"+delivery_or_pickup+"']").hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this will really depend on the entire scope of your code and there's an argument to be made either way. If there is a fair amount of specific targeting I would recommend the 2nd option where you add selector's to specific elements for two reasons:

**1. Less Typing** - I would give your inputs that need lots of querying specific IDs that are shorter than what you are currently selecting. i.e. `#name`. Then each time you need to query them you are using many less characters.

**2. Processing Efficiency and Speed** - After giving each of your inputs specific IDs, store them in variables so jQuery is doing DOM look-ups less frequently.

`var name = $('#name');`

This is good practice when you are looking up the same DOM elements repeatedly within your code. This is also a good way to improve code readability. This code:

`$("input[name='address'][data-type='delivery']").val("new value");`

can become:

`address.val("new value");`